Python Docx Followed Hyperlink Style not found
in the below code if i try to access the followed hyperlink style directly it does not work, if i try to create my own then it makes a duplicate called "FollowedHyperlink1", why is the built in "FollowedHyperlink" style not detected.
    dest_doc = Document(dest_file)

    dest_doc.styles["Normal"].font.name = "Arial"
    dest_doc.styles["Normal"].font.size = Pt(11)
    dest_doc.styles["Normal"].paragraph_format.line_spacing = 1
    dest_doc.styles["Normal"].paragraph_format.space_after = Pt(0)
    dest_doc.styles["Normal"].paragraph_format.space_before = Pt(0)
    dest_doc.styles["List Bullet 3"].paragraph_format.line_spacing = 1
    dest_doc.styles["Hyperlink"].font.color.rgb = RGBColor(20, 57, 111)
    dest_doc.styles["FollowedHyperlink"].font.color.rgb = RGBColor(20, 57, 111) # Does Not Work

    # Get or create the Followed Hyperlink style
    followed_hyperlink_style = None
    for style in dest_doc.styles:
        if style.name.lower() == "followedhyperlink":
            followed_hyperlink_style = style
            break

      if not followed_hyperlink_style:
         print("Creating Followed Hyperlink style...")
         followed_hyperlink_style = dest_doc.styles.add_style(
             "FollowedHyperlink", WD_STYLE_TYPE.CHARACTER
         )

    # Check if Followed Hyperlink style exists
    if followed_hyperlink_style:
        # Set color for followed hyperlinks
        followed_hyperlink_style.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(20, 57, 111)
    else:
        with open("missing_fh.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write(dest_file + "\n")
        print("Followed Hyperlink style not found.")

